# Distribute objects evenly according to their attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, web-scraping

I'm looking for a way how to evenly distribute objects according to their attributes to list.

For example:

```
[{'fruit':'apple', 'price':45},{'fruit':'apple', 'price':5},
 {'fruit':'orange','price':4},{'fruit':'orange','price':45},                                    
 {'fruit':'orange','price':8},{'fruit':'orange','price':450},]
```

I want to reorder this list to make all fruits of the same kind apart as much as possible. The solution for this simple example is:

```
[{'fruit':'orange', 'price':45},{'fruit':'apple', 'price':5},
 {'fruit':'orange','price':4},{'fruit':'apple','price':45},                                    
 {'fruit':'orange','price':8},{'fruit':'orange','price':450},]
```

So `orange,apple,orange,orange,apple,orange` is one of the correct solutions.

This is a simplified example. In fact, it is about scraping huge number of urls. I scrape those urls using pool of 100 workers. There can be multiple urls with the same site so I want to distribute them evenly because I don't want to overload someones server.

Do you have an idea what to solve this? Or is there some module which can do that?

Comment: What you mean by _apart as much as possible_ ? why apple items are not first and last items ?

Comment: Because there would be three oranges next to each other so this is a better solution.

Comment: Always two kind of `fruits` exists? Explain more please ! it's not really obvious what you are asking here.

Comment: @Arman I tried to explain it at the bottom of the question. In fact, it's the web scraping problem. I don't want to have for example 100 urls of one site next to each other because I don't want to overload server. The better way is to  distribute those urls across the queue/list so urls having the same site aren't scraped in one pool.

Comment: @Arman There can be any number of fruits there (sites).

Comment: Something like the ```roundrobin``` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) combined with itertools.groupby.

Comment: How about sort the urls and let _i_ th worker take `urls[j]` for all `j%10==i` ?
It should distribute the domains evenly... for example if there are 18 sites start with https://orange.com, followed by 20 https://apple.com, each of them will work on 1~2 oranges and 2 apples then.

Answer (score 1):

`roundrobin` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) combined with itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import cycle, groupby, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

earls = [{'fruit':'apple', 'price':45},{'fruit':'apple', 'price':5},
         {'fruit':'orange','price':4},{'fruit':'orange','price':45},
         {'fruit':'orange','price':8},{'fruit':'orange','price':450},]

key = operator.itemgetter('fruit')
earls.sort(key = key)
groups = (tuple(group) for key, group in groupby(earls, key))

for thing in roundrobin(*groups):
    print(thing)
```

Result:

```
{'fruit': 'apple', 'price': 45}
{'fruit': 'orange', 'price': 4}
{'fruit': 'apple', 'price': 5}
{'fruit': 'orange', 'price': 45}
{'fruit': 'orange', 'price': 8}
{'fruit': 'orange', 'price': 450}
>>>
```